# div not expanding its content when its neighbour div slides to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make something like [this website](https://snazzymaps.com/style/42/apple-maps-esque).
When I click on the arrow, the left div collapses and the right one expands.
The problem is that the content of the right div is not expanded !

Here is my html:

```
<div class="tools-bg">
    <div  class="tools">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="picture-holder">
      <div class="allpartsofthepic">
       <div id="row1" class="tr">
        <div id="prt1" class="td"></div>         
        <div id="prt2" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt3" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt4" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt5" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt6" class="td"></div>            
        <div id="prt7" class="td"></div>         
        <div id="prt8" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt9" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt10" class="td"></div>
        </div>
      </div> 
  </div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.tools-bg
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ededed;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    width: 350px;
 }
.tools
{
    margin: 40px;   
}
.arrow
{
   background-color: #ccc;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 167px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tr
{
    display:block;
}
.td
{
    width:278px; 
    height:265px;
    float:left;
}
.picture-holder
{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:450px;
    width:70%;
}
#prt1{ background-image:url("../image/01_01_01.png");}
#prt2{ background-image:url("../image/01_01_02.png");}
#prt3{ background-image:url("../image/01_01_03.png");}
#prt4{ background-image:url("../image/01_02_01.png");}
#prt5{ background-image:url("../image/01_02_02.png");}
#prt6{ background-image:url("../image/01_02_03.png");}
#prt7{ background-image:url("../image/01_03_01.png");}
#prt8{ background-image:url("../image/01_03_02.png");}
#prt9{ background-image:url("../image/01_03_03.png");}
#prt10{ background-image:url("../image/01_04_01.png");}
```

I think the problem is in my CSS, but I can't solve it. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the picture holder width before running the sliding animation, by simply subtracting the arrow width from the whole container.

Then you will be able to use CSS3 translates to animate them.

```js
$(function(){
  var totalWidth = $(document).width();
  var arrowWidth = $('.arrow').width();
  var holderWidth = totalWidth - arrowWidth;
  $('.picture-holder').width(holderWidth);
  $('.arrow').on('click', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('slide-left');
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.tools-bg
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ededed;
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    width: 350px;
 }
.tools
{
    margin: 40px;   
}
.arrow
{
   background-color: #ccc;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 167px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tr
{
    display:block;
}
.td
{
    width:278px; 
    height:265px;
    float:left;
}
.picture-holder
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:450px;
    width: 70%;
    background: cyan;
    -webkit-transform: translate(350px, 0);
}

.slide-left .arrow,
.slide-left .tools-bg{
  -webkit-transform: translate(-350px, 0);
}

.slide-left .picture-holder{
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
}

.tools-bg,
.arrow,
.picture-holder{
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tools-bg">
    <div  class="tools">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="picture-holder">
    <div class="allpartsofthepic">
     <div id="row1" class="tr">
        <div id="prt1" class="td"></div>         
        <div id="prt2" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt3" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt4" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt5" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt6" class="td"></div>            
        <div id="prt7" class="td"></div>         
        <div id="prt8" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt9" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt10" class="td"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html like this

```
<div class="tools-bg" id="leftSideBar">
    <div  class="tools">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow" onclick="collapse()"></div>
    <div class="picture-holder">
    <div class="allpartsofthepic">
     <div id="row1" class="tr">
        <div id="prt1" class="td"></div>         
        <div id="prt2" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt3" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt4" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt5" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt6" class="td"></div>            
        <div id="prt7" class="td"></div>         
        <div id="prt8" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt9" class="td"></div>
        <div id="prt10" class="td"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And add this javascript

```
<script>
check = 1;
function collapse(){
    if(check == 1){
        check = 0 ;
        document.getElementById("leftSideBar").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        check = 1;
        document.getElementById("leftSideBar").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe i can help you

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/276jyxcj/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    $('.left').toggle("slide");
})
```

});